# CDF probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> For random variable $X$ and $Y$ defined on the same sample space, let $U = \min\{X,Y\}$ and $V = \max\{X,Y\}$.
>
> a) Determine the CDF of $V$ in terms of the joint CDF of $X$ and $Y$
>
> b) Determine the CDF of $U$ in terms of the joint and marginal CDF of $X$ and $Y$.

Here's what I got.
$$\begin{align}F_V(v) =&~ \mathbb P(V \leqslant v) \\[1ex] =&~ \mathbb P(\max\{X,Y\} \leqslant v)\end{align}$$
Where should I go from here?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $P(\max\{X,Y\} \le v) = P(X \le v \land Y \le v)$

Comment: @Henry How does max{X,Y} <=v yield P(X <=v and Y <=v) ? Can you explain?

Comment: Think about it.  Having the maximum of $X$ and $Y$ being less than or equal to $8$ is equivalent to $X$ being less than or equal to $8$ *and* $Y$ being less than  or equal to $8$

Answer (score 3):

Since $V = \max\{X, Y\}$, we can have $V \leq v$ if and only if $X \leq v$ *and* $Y \leq v$.  (If either $X$ or $Y$ were greater than $v$, then $V$, their maximum, would necessarily be greater than $v$ also.)  As a result, we have the hint in Henry's comment:

$$
P(V \leq v) = P(X \leq v \wedge Y \leq v)
$$

On the other hand, since $U = \min\{X, Y\}$, we can have $U \leq u$ if and only if either $X \leq u$ *or* $Y \leq u$.  (If neither were the case, they would both have to be greater than $u$, and $U$, their minimum, would necessarily be greater than $u$ also.)  Thus, we have (by analogy with the above)

$$
P(U \leq u) = P(X \leq u \vee Y \leq u)
$$

Unlike the first expression, this is not in terms of the joint CDF.  However, we can make use of the inclusion-exclusion principle, which tells us that for any events $A$ and $B$, we have

$$
P(A \vee B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \wedge B)
$$

By letting $A$ represent "$X \leq u$" and $B$ represent "$Y \leq u$", you can get the expression into the desired form.